# String initialization difference

Tags: java, memory-management

Firstly apologies if this a very basic question, I'm just curious to know the difference between the following string definitions

```
String x= "hello";
String y = new String("hello");
```

I knew that in java String is a Class its neither a primitive nor a Wrapper(Correct me if this a misconception). Consider a class A, I've seen the following declarations for any class so far. i think `A c;` is valid and `A a = new A();` is also valid. I'm confused with `A a ="xyz";` this is how we declared a String as in above first type of definition. I'm sure that the above two definitions are absolutely different, like if i say `x==y` it returns false. I understand that y is the reference to the String object. What is x there, how is it stored in memory, interestingly i found that both x and y can access all the methods of String class.

Then what is the advantage of one over other.Can i know the applicability of each.

Comment: Note that you should be comparing Strings with .equals() and not ==

Comment: The reason `x == y` returns `False` is that `==` compares the references (or address) of the two objects and not their contents - and the references of x and y are different.

Like QPaysTaxes states, strings must be compared with `.equals()` to check their contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the 2nd edition of Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java":

> ```
> String s = new String("stringette");// DON'T DO THIS!
> ```
>
> The statement creates a new String instance each time it is executed,
>   and none of those object creations is necessary. The argument to the
>   String constructor ("stringette") is itself a String instance,
>   functionally identical to all of the objects created by the
>   constructor. If this usage occurs in a loop or in a frequently invoked
>   method, millions of String instances can be created needlessly. The
>   improved version is simply the following:
>
> ```
> String s = "stringette";
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The first couple of answers you got are incorrect. There **is** a difference between the two statements. But first, the `TL;DR` version: Use `String x = "hello";` in 99.99999% of situations.

The full answer:

The chief difference between those two is that in the first case, the string is implicitly [`intern`ed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29); in the second case, it is not. This is a very real difference, although it only comes into play in select situations. So in the first case, if you have any other strings with the same series of characters (`"hello"`), your `x` will refer to the one *shared object* that is used in all of those places (this is useful, since `String` instances are immutable). In the second case, you're explicitly saying you need (for whatever reason) to have a `String` instance with that sequence of characters which is **separate** from any others. There are very, very few reasons to do that.

With regard to `x==y`, in Java you compare strings for equality using `equals`, not `==`. The `==` operator when used with object references compares the *references* (e.g., do both variables point to the same object), not the object contents.

So: Prefer the first form to the second unless you have a good reason for doing the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "hello"; //this kind of declaration always return "singlton" instance.
String b = "hello";
String c = new String("hello"); //This kind of declaration always return a new instance.
```

SO
`a ==b;`
but 
`a !=c`

Comment: To be pedantic, the literal produces a flyweight rather than a singleton. Singleton implies there's only one instance of the class, whereas a flyweight has one instance for each distinct value (like an enum). 'Flyweight' is not a very common term these days, but it's still useful.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I know singltonis not accurate, that's why I wrapped it in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, the value of `x` is a String. A normal `java.lang.String`.

You're used to the idea that there are literals for primitive types (like, `7`, or `3.14159`, or `true`, or `'q'`), but it seems what you may not have realised is that there are literal forms for some object types too. The only ones i can think of are `java.lang.String`, where you can write `"hello"`, and `java.lang.Class`, where you can write `SomeClass.class`.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that y is the reference to the String object. What is x there[...]?

Both `x` and `y` are references to `String` objects. The `x` is a reference to an [intern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)ed string (as T.J. Crowder already wrote in his answer), the `y` is a reference to a second `String` object with the same content. This means:

```
x == y       --> false
x.equals(y)  --> true
y.equals(x)  --> true
```

> Then what is the advantage of one over other.Can i know the applicability of each.

*Always* use the first, direct version. The *only* valid exception which I ever encountered and found to be valid is test code which explicitly want to make sure, that the code to be tested does not use `==` for string comparisons but uses the proper `x.equals(y)` method.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to initialize String is

```
String str =("abc");
```

It seems at first that this would give an error (because of the brackets) but this doesn't. Surprisingly.