# What is the difference between String initializations by new String() and new String("") in Java?

Tags: java, string, initialization

What is the difference between the following two initializations in Java?

1. `String a = new String();`
2. `String b = new String("");`

Comment: Already a very similar post for this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555077/string-initialization-difference

Comment: possible duplicate of [String empty constructor in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430112/string-empty-constructor-in-java)

Comment: @Joe Although I'm shocked this doesn't exist already, I don't think that question is a duplicate of this one -- `String("")` is different from `""`.

Comment: I dont think you should use new String() either way. It does not need initialized and doing so only takes longer. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, they are *almost the same*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = new String();
    String s2 = new String(""); 
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // returns true.
}
```

Minor differences (rather insignificant) :

1. `new String();` takes less time to execute than `new String("");` because the copy constructor does a lot of stuff.
2. `new String("")` adds the empty String (`""`) to the String constants pool if it is not already present.

Other than this, there are no other differences

Note : The use of `new String("abc")` is almost always bad because you will be creating 2 Strings one on String constants pool and another on heap with the same value.

Comment: other difference -- `new String();` is also easy, and takes less time to type (means writing), so its preferable.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Why not just `""`?

Comment: @johnchen902 yes `= ""` is better, I was just comparing two given in question.

Answer (score 4):

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28%29) explains it beautifully

These are 2 different constructor calling

```
public String()
```

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents an
>   empty character sequence. Note that use of this constructor is
>   unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

```
public String(String original)
```

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the
>   same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly
>   created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit
>   copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary
>   since Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, different constructors will be invoked.

However, the resulting `String` objects will be identical by their content **and** equal (`a.equals(b)` will return `true`)

Answer (score 2):

In first case you create only one `String` object in second case two: `""` and `new String`, if `""` object not already exist in string pool.

> 1. Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents an
>    empty character sequence.
> 2. Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the
>    same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly
>    created string is a copy of the argument string.

Comment: Is the `""` being created at this point? or does it already exist in the interned strings pool?

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for question. If you not created another `""` string object earlier it will be created. If you create `""` string object earlier, value will be got from string pool.

Comment: My reading of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16785991/289086) suggests that the String interning is done at class load time (as its part of the constant pool for the class) - not when the method is called. Thus, no new string for `""` is created when the method is called. Just a minor correction (I think).

Answer (score 2):

TheLostMind is mostly correct, but I'd like to add that the copy constructor doesn't actually do that much:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#137

```
137  public String() {
138      this.value = new char[0];
139  }

151  public String(String original) {
152      this.value = original.value;
153      this.hash = original.hash;
154  }
```

Using the constant `""` will use the first constructor to create the object reference anyway, so it doesn't matter too much which one you use.

In any case, I would recommend using the string literal `""` because you can save an object reference if you use that string elsewhere.  Only use the String constructor if you really need a copy of that string that isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: I find it interesting that given a million-character string `foo`, the statement `bar = new string(foo);` will share the backing store, but the method call `foo.equals(bar)` will compare every character of that backing store to itself, rather than notice that both strings share the same backing store.

Comment: Well - Prior to java7u40, there was a lot going on in the copy constructor. Now, they have changed the design so that the same back-end array is used. In jdk 6 we used to create a new char array in the copy constructor :)

Answer (score 1):

The first is calling the default constructor and the second is calling the copy constructor in order to create a new string in each case.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely practical point of view, there is *zero* difference between those constructions, as there is never any reason to ever use either of them. They are both wasteful and over-complicated, and thus equally pointless.

To initialize a variable with the empty string, do:

```
String s = "";
```

That is shorter and plainer to type, and avoids creating *any* String objects, since the one shared `""` instance in the intern pool will certainly have already been loaded by some other class anyway.