# What is benefit of creating a duplicate String object in heap if the same string literal is created(or already present) in string constant pool area?

Tags: java, string

```
String str = new String(“my literal”);
```

In above statement ,two objects  would be created  ,one as String literal  “my literal” in  string constant pool  (If it's not present in  string pool)   and other in  heap   area  as  object  String(“my literal”)

Q-1 I know the benefit of  putting the  string literal in string pool area but  I am not able to think of  about the  benefit  of  creating  a  duplicate object in heap?

Q2- As I read in some stack over flow link: If  use of new String("my literal") is almost always bad because you will be creating 2 Strings one on String constants pool and another on heap with the same value ,then my question is why does Java creates duplicate object in heap? Why not java  just ignore creating in heap?

Comment: @Sotirios  Although it may looks duplicate but its not actually duplicate ,the link provided does not have answer of my question " about the benefit of creating a duplicate object in heap?"

Comment: If you scroll down to [neeraj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29535476/438154), you'll notice this quote from the javadoc: _Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable._ That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios but why does Java creates duplicate object in heap in this case ? Why not java just ignores creating object in heap as its already present in pool?

Comment: Because you explicitly used `new`.

Comment: @amarnathpatel Why do you think there are two objects, the value will only be added to the constant pool when you call str.intern(), otherwise not.

Comment: @Sotirios  So basically there is no benefit or use of this duplicate object in heap(and its like a overhead in case of String as in the example given in this question)  and it's just created because of explicitly using new keyword .  Please confirm if its correct understanding.

Comment: @amarnathpatel, that would be very confusing as in any other case you can be sure the reference returned from `new` is unique. If JDK starts optimizing that and return an instance that can be possibly held by other thread, it can break existing code that uses that object as for synchronization.

Comment: Have you seen this constructor used in real code? Or has someone told you there is a benefit to this? Just trying to understand why you are asking.

Comment: @Klitos  No ,i have not seen in real code actually but this  was once asked by an Java  interviewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is almost no benefit to calling the `String(String)` constructor with a literal string. There *used to be* a significant benefit to calling the `String(String)` constructor with a different string expression.

The literal is already a String, and String objects are immutable. More generally, for *any* String expression passed to the String(String) constructor, the constructor is usually unnecessary, because the argument is already an immutable String.

From the String(String) constructor documentation:

> `public String(String original)`
>
> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

**With older versions of Java (prior to 1.7.0_06), the String(String) constructor was more useful.** A String created by `String.substring()` could refer to the larger original String, and prevent it from being garbage collected. The `String(String)` constructor cut the ties to the larger String.

You asked:

> Q-1: ... The benefit of creating a duplicate object in heap?

Usually there is none. However, if you're using a String object in a context where object identity matters, you might want a different object. For example:

- You're using String objects as keys within a `IdentityHashMap`, and want only your own String objects to match.
- You want to synchronize on a string value provided by external code. You don't want any other code synchronizing on the same String object; it could lead to unexpected interference and deadlock. [This example provided by @biziclop in a comment below.]

> Q-2: ... why does Java creates duplicate object in heap?

Because you explicitly asked it to with `new String("my literal")`. If you use the `new` operator, you get a new object.

Comment: I think you mean `IdentityHashMap`. The answers you've given to their questions are repeated from the duplicate post. You should've just written this answer there.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean that. I looked at the post you cited *and* searched for other existing duplicates, and did not see the answer to this question.

Comment: Another area where object identity matters is synchronization. Though you'd be quite foolish to synchronize on a `String` handed to you by some external code, creating a duplicate would ensure there's no interference.

Comment: @biziclop - Good example. I've added it to the answer above, with attribution. Thanks!